# « Allumer » pour « comprendre de façon soudaine » ?

Tags: sens, québec, origine-ou-raison

On trouve un sens d'*allumer* intransitif pour *comprendre de façon soudaine* : « C’est alors que j’ai allumé : il parlait du chat ! » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/allumer)). Je ne l'ai trouvé qu'au Wiktionnaire.

- Reconnaît-on l'emploi, le comprend-on aussi à l'impératif (« allume !
  ») ?
- De quel sens d'*allumer* procède cette acception, quelle est son
  origine ?
- Est-ce un emploi récent/contemporain ?

Comment: Je ne connaissais même pas cette acceptation d'allumer. Peut-être que que ça peut venir soit de  « faire tilt » (qui veut dire aussi bien « comprendre de façon soudaine » que « s'allumer » -. Ou peut-être du sens d'allumer « faire feu/tirer » (un peut tiré par les cheveux quand même !)

Comment: @None Ça pourrait être plus régional, vu que je le reconnais. Je le rattache à des trucs comme la référence au manque d'intelligence quand on dit qu'une personne n'est pas une _lumière_, voire pas une _100 watt_, le dernier assurément régional. Je sais pas trop.

Comment: Jamais entendu cela dans ce sens en Belgique en tout cas, ni remarqué dans les médias français. Peut-être un usage québécois ? Ou une expression relativement nouvelle employée par les plus jeunes qui m'aurait échappé ?

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas cette acceptation non plus, j'imagine qu'elle est peu utilisée (en France métropolitaine en tout cas). D’où je viens (région parisienne) on dirait plutôt "percuter" ou "capter" (même si les deux sont plutôt familiers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hexagonale pure souche, si quelqu'un me dit que je suis allumée je comprends qu'il me dit que je suis givrée, zinzin, chtarbée...  Mais s'il est québécois, c'est différent.

L'expression « être allumé » est définie ainsi dans *[Le lexique québécois à destination des futurs étudiants de l’Université de Montréal](https://admission.umontreal.ca/fileadmin/fichiers/objectif-udem/Lexique-web_OK.pdf)* :

> **Être allumé** : être (r)éveillé, attentif

Le blogueur québécois Olivier Roland définit ainsi l'expression :

> [être allumé, c’est être intelligent](https://olivier-roland.tv/ces-expressions-quebecoises-inconnues-en-france-et-inversement-infusees-au-vin-200365/).

Donc cette expression inconnue en France veut dire qu'on est bien réveillé, attentif, apte à comprendre facilement, donc qu'on est intelligent.

On trouve bien sûr l'emploi à la voix active et aussi à l'impératif :

> « [Non, mais allume ! » « Y vas-tu finir par allumer ?](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/lexique/definition-expression/canada/allume/) »

Faire le lien entre « allumer » et la lumière semble logique. Sur le [blog La Rochelle-Québec](http://larochelle-quebec.fr/?p=310) on trouve la variante « allumer ses lumières ».

> *Allumer ses lumières* : comprendre enfin quelque chose qui nous est expliqué (on dit aussi: Allume tes lumières pis arrive en ville ou Allume tes lumières, on arrive en ville)

Si cet emploi du verbe allumer est spécifique au Québec, l'association lumière-idée/intelligence est plus universelle. Les plus vieux d'entre nous connaissons le personnage de dessin animé Géo Trouvetou<sup>1</sup>, inventeur souvent représenté avec une ampoule éclairée dans la main ou au-dessus de sa tête, et les plus jeunes connaissent l'émoji « idée » représenté par une ampoule allumée.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>: *Gyro Gearloose* pour les anglophones.</sup>