# Conveying 'It's raining cats and dogs'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, weather

One expression that I consider a 'classic' in English is  (another one [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38354/french-equivalent-of-my-cup-of-tea)):

> It's raining cats and dogs.

This phrase is used to convey heavy and intense rainfall. While there is no direct translation in French, I have come across two similar expressions:

- The first one is 'Il pleut des cordes,' which conveys the sense of a significant downpour.
- The second one is 'Il pleut comme une vache qui pisse.'

However, in my understanding, both of these expressions might fall short in capturing the vivid imagery of the English expression. Am I correct? Are there any other expressions closer to the English meaning?

Comment: could you clarify why you think those expressions "fall short in capturing the vivid imagery of the English expression" ?

Comment: These sort of phrases never translate directly. *Il pleut des cordes* is the exact equivalent in terms of imagery and frequency and a great classic.  You can see [here](https://www.faxinfo.fr/expression-expliquee-il-pleut-des-cordes) // And other phrases [here](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/tomber-des-cordes/page-7) but not as frequent, on peut ajouter aussi *il pleut à seaux* mais encore moins employé.

Comment: [Stop Saying "It's Raining Cats and Dogs!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKMmAGnLUhA) :-)

Comment: @None Merci, j'avais jamais allumé avant aujourd'hui que _siaux_ c'était _seaux_ ahaha !

Comment: As someone who grew up with "raining cats and dogs" I must say that the expression *Il pleut des cordes* seems more accurate to what this kind of rain actually sounds like.

Comment: @Plusjamaisquoiencore T'avais pas « allumé » :  c'est courant au Québec ? Familier ? En France  je ne l'ai jamais entendu dans ce sens,  ici on dit qu'on n'a pas percuté, c'est familier.

Comment: @None Mais oui on l'a déjà entendu... dans ma question ;-) https://french.stackexchange.com/q/46977

Comment: @Plusjamaisquoiencore LOL!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Il pleut des cordes* is the exact equivalent to "[it's raining cats and dogs](https://www.loc.gov/everyday-mysteries/meteorology-climatology/item/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-its-raining-cats-and-dogs/)" in terms of imagery and frequency and a great classic. These sort of phrases never have exact equivalents because they are rooted in the History
and traditions of a country.

*Il pleut des cordes* is by far the most frequent colloquial expression to say the it's raining heavily. It conveys the optical illusion of the raindrops being all attached we seem to see one continuous flood coming down from the sky.

*Il pleut comme vache qui pisse** is probably a more "vivid image" but not so frequent, and a different register, it's a lot more informal.

One vivid image is probably [*il pleut des hallebardes*](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/tomber-des-cordes). It is older than *il pleut des cordes* and does not sound informal, but it is  much less widely used. Victor Hugo used it in *Les Misérables* :

> il lansquine, il pleut, vieille figure frappante, qui porte en quelque sorte sa date avec elle, qui assimile les longues lignes obliques de la pluie aux piques épaisses et penchées des lansquenets, et qui fait tenir dans un seul mot la métonymie populaire : il pleut des hallebardes.

Other images are *il pleut des seaux* (which I gather from [Plus jamais quoi encore's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/54133/358) seems to be more frequent in Quebec French), as is [*il pleut des clous*](http://etoile-de-lune.net/edl/quebec/19-lexique.html).

---

* <sub>It's usually *comme vache qui pisse*, no indefinite article.</sub>

Comment: Il drache (Belg.), il tombe des rabanelles (Lang.).

Comment: il roille (Suisse)

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think the statement is correct. Often nothing seems as idiomatic as one's native or main language, although sometimes the opposite occurs and one is perceiving overly metaphorical imagery when the native speaker doesn't. In any case the expressions you suggested do convey the meaning in my opinion, as well as imagery, albeit a different one.

I'll add two other expressions/variations from Quebec:

> *Il [pleut](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/pleuvoir) à siaux* (an modified form for *[seau](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/siau)x*; QC using that form/pronunciation).
> *Il [pleut](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/pleuvoir) à boire debout.* (QC)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would like to use "Il pleut à torrents" which technically means that it rains enough to create huge streams of rushing water.

Comment: *Il pleut à torrent* doesn't convey any imagery as asked in the question. The word is used for any great amount of water (a flood of water).

Answer (score 1):

*Il pleut à verse* serves for pouring heavily.  Quite common phrasing for pouring rain, though idiomatically perhaps not as expressive in imagery.  *Il pleut à cordes* fits the bill there as noted but à verse not to be omitted.

[Il pleut à verse](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/il-pleut-%C3%A0-verse#:%7E:text=It%27s%20raining.,pouring%20%E2%A7%AB%20it%27s%20pouring%20down) chez Collins.

Comment: J'ai surtout entendu *il pleut **des** cordes*, mais on trouve bien quelques *à cordes*, peut être influencés par *à verse* ?

Comment: On dirait aussi ça peut être influencé par le clavier T9, la suggestion ou la saisie de texte inattendue et son vérification de merde de l'orthographe @jlliagre moi aussi je préfère **des** cordes.  Au moins c'est pas *il pleut *averse.*

Comment: [It's reigning cats and dogs](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/7c0ee5a2-48ff-4a08-9322-237213cca3e4/gif)